# Invalid pin error Raspberry Pi Pico micropython

Tags: pi-pico, micropython

I'm currently doing a project using all of the GPIO pins on the raspberry pi pico. I want to configure pins 31, 32 and 34 (GP26, 27 and 28) as outputs but keep getting the 'invalid pin' error. No idea what I'm doing wrong as the other pins all seem to be happy as outputs. The only difference I can see is that these 3 pins can also be used for the ADC.

Here's what I've done:

```
from machine import pin

#control pins
W = Pin(31, Pin.OUT) #GPIO 26
PROG = Pin(32, Pin.OUT) #GPIO 27
HLT = Pin(34, Pin.OUT) #GPIO 28
#Data Pins
D0 = Pin(1, Pin.OUT) #GPIO 0
```

This is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 42, in <module>
ValueError: invalid pin
```

The data pin D0 is quite happy being an input but the others not so much. Any ideas anyone?

Comment: Noticed syntax error sorry. Pin is capitalised in the first line. Still not working

Comment: The Pin method takes the GPIO number not the physical number!

Comment: Thank you @CoderMike

Comment: Issue seems to be gone. Such a simple fix!

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment, the machine.Pin constructor uses the GPIO number rather than the physical pin number.

https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/library/machine.Pin.html?highlight=pin#constructors

Pico pinout:
https://pico.pinout.xyz